# Get username on form submission when form is embedded

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been modifying the Help Desk tutorial script found here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial

Since this is for internal use only, I removed the "Contact Email" field and set the form log the Username to the spreadsheet. I've edited the formSubmitReply function compensate:

Original:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
var userEmail = e.values[3];
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
    "Help Desk Ticket",
    "Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nWe'll start " +
    "working on it as soon as possible. \n\nHelp Desk",
    {name:"Help Desk"});
}​
```

Modified:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
var userEmail = e.user;
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
    "Help Desk Ticket",
    "Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nWe'll start " +
    "working on it as soon as possible. \n\nHelp Desk",
    {name:"Help Desk"});
}​
```

As you can see, all I've done is change how the userEmail variable is defined. When I view the Live Form and submit a ticket, it seems to work.

However, after I embedded the form into an internal Google site (our "intranet"), it no longer works.

Is there a way that I need to define userEmail to work when the form is embedded?

I also tried this:

```
var userEmail = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Username")).getValue();
```

But had no luck. Any help would be appreciated! I'm obviously new at this and just trying to hack a few things to get it working properly.

Cheers

Comment: Can you be more specific about the way in which "it no longer works"?  Do you get an error, and if so what and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is apparently being constructed differently for the embedded form.

Try:

```
var userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
```

That will be independent of the event, and should identify the user running the script.