# Collecting UserAgent in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, user-agent, google-forms

I'm trying to collect the user agent for responses to a Google Form.  Is it possible to do this with the Google Script Editor? If so, can you give me some pointers on how?

Thanks!

Jacqueline

Answer (score 0):

I needed this too and toyed with [replicating the form myself](https://codeburst.io/avoid-databases-by-hacking-a-google-form-d20cd2b6a020#.s2v5e4ung) and adding a new hidden field, but this seemed:

1. Risky. (Google might blacklist my form.)
2. Unlikely to work as there would be no handler for this field on the Google server side.

So I embedded the Google form in my app and added a button immediately above the it that copies the user agent string to the clipboard using [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/). (I use jQuery to build the page that the Google form is embedded in, but you will get the idea.)

```
let $systemInfoButton = $(`<a id="copy-user-agent" class="plain-button" data-clipboard-text="${navigator.userAgent}">Copy System Info</a>`);
...
new ClipboardJS('#copy-user-agent');
```

And then I added a field called 'System Info' to my Google form (just before the submit button)  asking the user to click the button and paste the result into the field before submit. Could make this required.

Not great, but it will do for now - until I come up with a better solution that does this automatically (which probably means doing it all myself or using another form provider).

Answer (score -2):

[**Collecting the Email or Name of Form Respondents:**](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/forms/LZpAOE4VFSI)
If you are on a Google Apps Domain, you can select the checkbox at the top of the Form Editor that says  “automatically collect respondent's yourdomain.com username.” If you are not on a Google Apps domain, you will have to include a question that asks for email or name.

As for using a script, take a look at this related post: [Get username on form submission when form is embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343848/get-username-on-form-submission-when-form-is-embedded). Since this method is using a script, it may require your form users to approve script access to their identity (at least on the first use) which may seem fishy to many users depending on the form purpose. It may be easier to simply include a question if you are not on a domain.

If you are building your own forms using the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) of Google Apps Script, you will have a little more control. Take a look at the formResponse method "getRespondentEmail()".

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I'm not looking for the username of the respondent, but rather their **user agent** - the string that represents the browser and device that they were responding from. For example, my user agent right now is "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36". Any idea if it's possible to pull that in?